# Iterate through keys and values of a Json string in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I'm tring to parse a json string that looks like this:

```
{ "a": [{
    "b": [
        ["c"],
        []
    ], "d": [
        [],
        []
    ], "e": [
        [],
        ["f"]
    ], "g": [
        [],
        ["h", "i"]
    ]
}] }
```

I'm using the code below to parse it and iterate through the keys and values. However, besides the keys and values that I expect, I get some numbers as keys which I guess are the index numbers of those that don't have any keys. How can I modify the code (pure javascript) so that I only get "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i" as keys and values and nothing more?

```
var jsonData = JSON.parse("name");
for (var key in jsonData) {
  if (jsonData.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    // do stuff
  }
}
```

Comment: jsonData["a"] would give you the access to the next level

Comment: What are expected results? Not clear what you are asking when you say you want those letters *"as keys and values"*

Comment: The "keys" of an Array are numbers representing indexes of values in the list. All of the letters in the Arrays are actually "values", whereas they are "keys" in the Objects.  So, you need to handle them differently.

Comment: In your expected output, you've excluded "f"; is that deliberate?

Comment: @tavnab No, it wasn't. I fixed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a recursive solution to walk through the data structure. When the parameter is an array, it will iterate and recurse through each element; when the it's an object, it will output each key and recurse through each value; otherwise, it will just output the string representation of the parameter.

```js
var data = { "a": [{
    "b": [
        ["c"],
        []
    ], "d": [
        [],
        []
    ], "e": [
        [],
        ["f"]
    ], "g": [
        [],
        ["h", "i"]
    ]
}] };

function walk(a) {
  if (Array.isArray(a)) {
    a.map(walk);
  } else if (typeof a === 'object') {
    Object.keys(a).forEach(key => {
      console.log(key);
      walk(a[key]);
    });
  } else {
    console.log(a);
  }
}

walk(data);
```

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem. I was trying this except that I was checking for 'object' first and then 'array' which I guess is wrong as 'object' is the superclass.

Comment: That's a good solution too; I went with the explicit `Array.isArray()` call for clarity's sake

Answer (score 0):

Based on example shown you could use a regex on the json string:

```js
let data = {
  "a": [{
    "b": [
      ["c"],
      []
    ],
    "d": [
      [],
      []
    ],
    "e": [
      [],
      ["f"]
    ],
    "g": [
      [],
      ["h", "i"]
    ]
  }]
};

let res = JSON.stringify(data).match(/\w+/g);
console.log(res.join())
```

Comment: This is `*chef finger kiss*` clever!